# Can't put TextView element above ExpandableListView when windowTranslucentNavigation=true

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

I need smt like on this image with translucent NavBar :

[image]

But it works only when ***windowTranslucentNavigation*** is ***false***.

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/elvMainFragment"
          android:name="com.example.ExpListView_Events.FragmentExpListView"
          tools:layout="@layout/elv_fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**elv_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:id="@+id/tvMainText"
          android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:text="Hello!"
          android:gravity="center"
        />

<ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Have any ideas without using padding/margin?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution would be to use a ***RelativeLayout*** instead of a ***LinearLayout***, it'll give you the possibility to say "this ***ExpandableListView*** goes under the ***TextView***".

To do this you must do something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:id="@+id/tvMainText"
          android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:text="Hello!"
          android:gravity="center"/>

<ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvMainText"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

(The trick is in this line :)

```
android:layout_below="@id/tvMainText"
```

I didn't test it but it should work :)

Comment: I had tried it before but it didn't work :( Result: http://i.imgur.com/5WqkUjp.png There is a problem with fitsSystemWindows and clipToPadding attributes. If I add "fitsSystemWindows = true" to the LinearLayout - it will be displayed normally, but ExpListView won't scroll under NavBar. Example: http://i.imgur.com/A46Z09I.png P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: (No problem, your English is fully understandable). I think I need your ExpendableListView code, to go further. When you (or I) don't find any solution, I think the "best dirty solution" will be to add relative margins with the size of the screen (for example : List View Up Margin is 5% of the height of the screen).